# Corrupted File - Git

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have a github remote repo with a README and a LICENSE. I then commit and push the changes from my local repo to my remote one. Everything seems to be going fine until I browse the files that I just uploaded on Github. First it says they're too big(even though it's a 200 line php file), so I downloaded the file. It looked like this:

```
IHDR  szzÙ$iCCPICC Profile8ÖUﬂo€T>âoR§? XGáä≈ØUS[π≠∆Iì•ÌJ•Èÿ*$‰:7â©€È∂™O{Å7¸@ŸH<!
b{Ÿˆ¿¥ISá*™IH{Ëƒ!&ÌU·ªvb'Sƒ\ı˙À9ﬂ9Á;Á^€D=_iµöUàñ´Æùœ$ïìßîûMä“≥‘K‘´ÈN-ëÀÕ.¡˜ŒÎ·äÀÌëÓ˛Nˆ#øzã‹—â"O¿n}¯QÃ‘k∂Kø˚¯i∑‹Û”6´ó}úx—«'=N!? é–*Î≠º<ºÿf/∑a_»ì·Un∫"fë≥≠íarœ·/èq∑1ˇ.õuÙÏ]ÉX˚ú•πc∏âﬁ+ˆTæâ?◊µÙK∞_ØπIa¯è˙“|xQÙ©í}tﬁÁG__≠ﬁﬁ{—pßM˚ju1{±—ı%Îò»#8◊ug≥§ÄÔV¯¥ÿcËë®»Si‡a‡¡J}™ô_öqVÊÑ›À≥ZôÃ#èdøßÕ‰ÄÄ?¥≠º®Õ“:73¢ÚKWknÆ©A⁄ÆöYQ˝2ô;^è»)mªï¬îÀ∫v°ÀJ∆—È&≠fzg⁄ÿªû⁄êü›“Ïtyÿ?º:/Ê€]‘Rb∂£¿GËDD#N-b’©J;§Pû2îƒΩF6<%2»ÑÖ√Àa1"O“l›y9è„«Ñå≤Ω-¢Q•;«Øpø…±X?SŸ¸b≥Ï0g§∞7ÿõÏK¡:¡
rm:*”}(ıÛºOuT:NPÚ¸@}(àQŒŸÔ˙Õè˛Üö∞K+Ù#O–14[Ì hu7“>ßkk?Ï< ª¯ŒÌækkt¸qÛç›ãm«6∞n∆∂¬¯ÿØ±-¸mR;`zäñ° v¬    x#=\”%
Îo‡Y–⁄R⁄±£•Í˘Å–#&¡?»>Ã“π·–™˛¢˛©n®_®‘ﬂ;jÑ;¶$}*}+˝(}'}/˝LätY∫"˝$]ïæë.9ªÔΩü%ÿ{Ø_a›ä]h’kü5'SN {‰Âî¸º¸≤<∞π_ìß‰ΩÏ    ˆÕ˝Ωt
≥jMµ{-Ò4%ù◊∆T≈Ñ´tY€üì¶R6»∆ÿÙ#ßv\úÂñäx:ûä'HâÔãOƒ«‚3∑ûº¯^¯&∞¶ı˛ì0::‡m,L%»3‚ù:qVEÙ
tõ–Õ]~ﬂ¢I´v÷6 WŸØ™Ø)    | ∏2]’GáÕ4œÂ(6w∏Ω¬ã£$æÉ"éËAﬁ˚æEv›mÓ[Dáˇ¬;ÎVh[®}Ìıø⁄ÜN|Ê3¢ãı∫Ω‚Á£H‰ëS:∞ﬂ˚ÈK‚›t∑—xÄ˜Uœ'D;7ˇÆ7;_"ˇ—eÛ?Yqxl+   pHYs%%IR$  ¶IDATX  ≠Wkl◊˛Ê±≥3˚Ú>lÔ⁄f±!ÊUbﬁ‡
µNEArmP´©EQ•VTàUj˚áJQy®i®µQ‘(Q•Vä®°V!!§iƒîáçIL`cºˆÆΩkÔ{wvfzŒÿÎ:@»ü^˘˙ﬁπwˆûÔ|˜;Áﬁ,À¬gÅ
Õ…T%™¸bÖﬁ7®˝ø·Al¥∑∑˜ßNß∫∫®óeS•´◊'≈ÊyöÂ÷dS®X”‘ÈgÉÉÆÎ(óÀV°PÄiöF6õΩ∫wÔﬁ7«««áËùÚÁ!eÔ,™ IﬂâFÁ≠®òb£&N›ÃcY¯÷WBp9®ËCgÉveπ\ôLí$·–°Cù¸˘ré@40˜Yú˚0”óMK0t√¿¿Ω^>1àªπ$^˚`ÈC*ìÉN∆uΩÇJ•b3¿@dY∂k>üG$˘“·√á_Z¥h—f·zÑçŸ°Ox˝˘gÇ´€WGEEså§ºzÚ6.OdY≥Åh=^ª0Ç∑z“(UL(.èmê=Ê™(
‹n74MC<«∫uÎ⁄8"ÅË$ÓYãtÏ-xı[j÷o~˜’
ÂŒım+~ÁÇÁËçÂ∏ú»¬π¨¬‰,*0‰z¸·?√§»lÙu√]ﬂ-–ãÿb»TUµYa@õ7o^Bc/Ïﬂø_¶ˆ⁄éÏˆa3p%=·˛‡rrÌ·cÂRˇ}ØWøÛg◊ï;wPZ∫Î§”x)zª√Ø¬mM!ÿ‡«œBO≈çè!5ïß:!k ùN€`DQD0ƒ÷≠[ü8r‰»ÌÌÌ€ ÑÔ!4(ˇ˛ºïˇ…øûÿs¬˚|◊†–   ØcŸêÇ∏¨‡õû˜p¸„ZhbMôb“p ‘FIÚ£RGæl¿„ı¬ÌÒÿﬁ3.ó===8yÚ$Œü?è∫∫∫Ê}˚ˆ˝™££„€dœ?ÑåÂÀ}Å≈mçÀ;ˆl+N»_7
)-ß»∏/y‡Ssà écK±”;äﬁ€xk(±•Ü¡ƒ–._J‚πŒfXÂ\§
I§R)3R*ïl&©lﬂæ˝1%àø“vL2Y≠   {∑=˜åë0vWdS[µ0ñ– zÉP$À¶3'◊¬r§)
ç√“ãΩóEræ   √*·
fƒÔ≈”Î†8$»$H¶ﬂK¨pDê1€aéß”Yøm€∂uww«h¸Å–ÂÄˇÈÌ©¡ÙèÔL
iÆUK)ƒ&ëÃ+0≠í¢Å\@AX)°—ù√ÈºrSïËñ
Xä
..........
```

And a lot more. I then deleted the remote repo, deleted the local .git dir and tried again, with the same result. But, the local files remained the same - readable .php files.

Has anyone else had this problem before, and/or knows how to fix it?

### Exact steps:

Make remote git repo

Edit local files

```
$ git init
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
$ git push --force https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

And, like I said before, all seems to go well - no error messages or anything -  until I see the files that were pushed.

### Edit

Head slap!

The files that were being uploaded were *aliases* of files in another directory. Once I got the real files it worked.

Comment: `IHDR` is a header used by the PNG format. Are you sure you uploaded the right things?

Comment: I'm sure, because I don't have any images in the repo. And, this happened to all files that I uploaded. Plus, the filenames match the .php files

Comment: Can you try downloading the file and opening it as an image?

Comment: Just tried to convert to PNG and JPG. Tells me the file is damaged

Comment: If this is a public repo, perhaps you could share it here? Will help in troubleshooting.